# Variable number of arguments for pyspark udf

Tags: pyspark, udf

I have around `275` columns and  I would like to search `25` columns for a regex string `"^D(410|412)`. If this search string is is present in any of `2`5 columns I would like to add `true` to `MyNewColumn`.

using below I could do it for `2` columns. Is there anyway for passing variable number of columns ?

**Below code works for 2 columns**

```
def moreThanTwoArgs(col1,col2): 
return bool((re.search("^D(410|412)",col1) or re.search("^D(410|412)",col2)))

twoUDF= udf(moreThanTwoArgs,BooleanType())
df = df.withColumn("MyNewColumn", twoUDF(df["X1"], df["X2"]))
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried some what similar have sample code try this and proceed:-

```
df1 = sc.parallelize(
        [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
    ]).toDF(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10'])
df1.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|c10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+


import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import re

def booleanFindFunc(*args):
    return sum(args)

udfBoolean = F.udf(booleanFindFunc, T.StringType())


#Below is Sum of three columns (c1+c2+c2)
df1.withColumn("MyNewColumn", booleanFindFunc(F.col("c1"), F.col("c2"), F.col("c2"))).show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|c10|MyNewColumn|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|          5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+



#Below is Sum of All Columns (c1+c2+c3---+c10)
df1.withColumn("MyNewColumn", booleanFindFunc(*[F.col(i) for i in df1.columns])).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|c10|MyNewColumn|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         55|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+

#Below is Sum of All odd Columns (c1+c3+c5--+c9)
df1.withColumn("MyNewColumn", booleanFindFunc(*[F.col(i) for i in df1.columns if int(i[1:])%2])).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|c10|MyNewColumn|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|         25|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----------+
```

Hope This will solve your problem